# Problems with special letters in ubuntu server

Tags: html, ubuntu-server

I am trying to host a website on my local connection, i already have a dedicated machine running ubuntu server 16.04 for i386.
I am writing my html and css code on vscode from my pc and then i pass it on the server using putty sftp , but when i display the webpage from the internet it changes some special letters ( the "ù" becames "Ã¹", the "é" becames "Ã¨")

this is the html code: https://pastebin.com/bqV1D3yX
note: i'm italian and the text showed up in the page is all italian, i have checked and the ubuntu machine read the text correctly but the browser doesn't.
this is how the page looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HdWd.jpg

note2: i know i could bypass the problems by using the ' but i would prefer not

note3: i know the code is very far to be well written but i have just started

Comment: Maybe use utf8 on your `<head>`? Like: `<meta charset="UTF-8">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a server problem. You're missing the [charset declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Introduction_to_HTML5#Declaring_the_character_set_with_the_%3Cmeta_charset%3E) in your `<head>`. It should match your file's encoding, which nowadays is typically UTF-8:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

The browser tries to guess correct encoding and fails at it. Adding the charset declaration will fix this.